# Apple's Passbook or Google's Wallet

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, passbook, android-pay

I would like to make use of digital passes that can be used both on iOS and Android devices. For this I could use Passbook or Google Wallet, since both exists for the two platforms. The one thing that I am still wondering about: which versions do support the push notifications?

If I understand correctly, the passbook application on android can only display the different passes, but can not receive the push notifications from the APNS (Apple push notification service). Is this also true for the passes in Google Wallet (does the Google Wallet app for iOS also not support the push notifications)?

Comment: There are several passbook apps for Android and they support push notifications. PassWallet is one. I've recently implement support in PassVerse for it and it was very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update Wallet Object content which is automatically pushed to any device with Google Wallet (both Android and iOS).

As of now, users won't receive an Android notification for any updates, but the Object will be updated.  We're still working on how to enable notifications with out overly spamming consumers.